# How do add one double quotation mark (") into a string in VB.NET?

Tags: string, vb.net

Currently I have

```
codeString &= "matrixDictionary(" & Chr(34) & UCase(Mid(currentPhrase, currentPhrase.Count, 1)) & Chr(34) & " )"
```

To codeString I want this to add

```
matrixdictionary("A")
```

However, currently, it's adding

```
matrixdictionary(""A"")
```

How do I add a " to a string on it's own? I've tried looking it up, but every other method suggested doesn't see to work, or isn't relevant.

Comment: There is no problem to solve. A literal double quote is represented in a string by two double quotes, with the first escaping the second. If you output that string to the console or a label or whatever, you'll see that it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem to solve here. A literal double-quote is simply represented by two double-quotes, with the first escaping the second in order to distinguish it from a delimiter. These all produce equal `String` objects:

```vb
Dim str1 = "He said " & Chr(34) & "Hello" & Chr(34) & " to me."
Dim str2 = "He said " & ControlChars.Quote & "Hello" & ControlChars.Quote & " to me."
Dim str3 = "He said ""Hello"" to me."
```

The first one - the one you're using - is the worst option because it is not self-documenting like the second or succinct and easy to read like the third. Output any of those three values, e.g. to the console or a `Label`, and you will see this:

```
He said "Hello" to me.
```

In your specific case, you should be using literal double-quotes and string interpolation:

```vb
codeString &= $"matrixDictionary(""{Mid(currentPhrase, currentPhrase.Count, 1).ToUpper()}"" )"
```

I've also replaced `UCase`, which is a VB6 holdover, with `ToUpper`. I'd suggest doing the same for `Mid` with `Substring`. Finally, I've left it in but I suspect that you have an erroneous space in your `String` too, before the closing parenthesis.